# Il y en a qui s'en viennent

Tags: usage, régionalismes, québec

Je suis Français et j'ai entendu pour la première fois cette phrase au Canada, qui ressemble à l'opposé de notre « qu'ils s'en aillent ».

En France nous dirions plutôt « il y en a qui arrivent ». Y a-t-il des traces de cet usage dans d'autres pays francophones ou bien est-ce purement canadien ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ce n'est pas purement canadien, ne serait-ce que par le contre-exemple que constitue cet usage dans la chanson de Brel *Il peut pleuvoir* :

> [...]
>
> Et aux gens **qui s'en viennent**
>
> Et aux gens qui s'en vont
>
> Jour et nuit tournez en rond
>
> Et aux gens **qui s'en viennent**
>
> Et aux gens qui s'en vont
>
> Moi je crie à pleins poumons
>
> [...]

J'ajouterais à titre personnel, en tant que français (du nord-est), qu'on entend rarement cette forme car elle est vieillie, en effet, mais elle ne m'était pas inconnue.

**Edité :** élément de confirmation, le wiktionnaire nous [donne](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_venir) d'autres exemples d'emploi hors-Canada (notamment chez Molière)

**Edité (bis) :** D'autres usages en poésie, qui ne m'étaient pas revenus tout de suite :

- Le poème d'Aragon *Lorsque s'en vient le soir* est un bon exemple d'usage de cette forme qui ne soit pas construit en opposition avec *s'en aller*.
- Même chose pour ce passage de la (sublime) *Chanson du mal aimé* d'Apollinaire :

> C'est le printemps **viens-t'en** Pâquette
>
> Te promener au bois joli
>
> Les poules dans la cour caquètent
>
> L'aube au ciel fait de roses plis
>
> L'amour chemine à ta conquête

Comment: J'allais aussi citer Brel... associée à « s'en aller », la locution me semble encore assez courante, mais aucune des occurrences isolées du wiktionnaire ne me semble naturelles.