# Is “s'en venir” + adjective a regionalism?

Tags: expressions, traduction, régionalismes

A translation style guide I read through issues the following recommendation (paraphrased):

> Il ne faut pas employer « s'en venir » dans le sens de « devenir ».
>
> <strike>*Elle s'en vient folle.*</strike> *Elle devient folle.*

There are a few recommendations in this guide that make me wonder: are they addressing absurd calques from other languages the translators on their rosters speak, or are these discouraged alternatives actually *courant* in the *langue populaire* ?

If I listen as I walk down the streets of a Francophone city, will I hear « Il s'en vient + adjectif » ?

<sub>(This is not a question about *devenir*, which I know is correct.)</sub>

Comment: As far as France is concerned, you should never hear that in a big city. However, local dialects may have an influence. For me "elle s'en vient folle" is more something I could hear in a movie taking place in the 17th century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, on l'entendra au Québec et je ne le trouve pas inusité à l'oral (je suis locuteur natif du français québécois). La *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (OQLF) l'associe à l'emploi ancien (15<sup>e</sup> au 17<sup>e</sup>) et maintenant régional et familier de [*venir* avec comme sens *devenir*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5236) (*Il ne faut quand même pas venir fou avec ça!*) mais avec une *idée de progression* :

> La haie **a poussé**; il faudrait penser à la tailler. (ou, plus familièrement : **s’en vient haute**) (BDL)

On s'explique mal l'origine du tour. D'autre part dans certains cas d'emploi pronominal avec le pronom *en*, ce dernier n'est parfois plus perçu comme marquant l'origine depuis fort longtemps (par ex. *s'en aller* : *Li marchis s'en en ala en son païs*, Robert de Clari, ds. *Le bon usage* 14<sup>e</sup> ed. § 681 b 1, semi-agglutination, note H8 ; voir aussi [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13958)). À mon avis un phénomène comme l'agglutination aide la sémantique non spatiale. On évoque un *translation style guide* : on tente possiblement d'éviter les régionalismes et le registre familier à la fois ; la BDL recommande elle aussi, dans un registre plus neutre, d'employer *devenir, se faire* ou le verbe simple selon le contexte...

Comment: Merci, c'est fort intéressant ! Oui, j'ai l'impression que ce guide a tendance à neutraliser la langue un peu. (C'est étrange toutefois qu'à l'Ontario on apprend un français européen, n'est-ce pas ? J'ai le Québec à une distance de quelques heures en auto et personne ne m'a indiqué l'existence de cette expression ni de tellement d'autres ...)

Answer (score 1):

In France, I've never heard or seen the usage you described (as a possible confusion with *devenir*), although I guess there might be some regional uses that I'm not aware of, mainly Quebec I guess ?

However, you should note that the idiom "s'en venir" **does** exist (even [on SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/il-y-en-a-qui-sen-viennent/)!), it's an old-fashioned way of saying "venir (ici)". The chances you hear it in a french street, theatrical performances aside, are increasingly slim with time passing...