# Quelle est la difference entre les verbes « aller » et « s'en aller » ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, verbes-pronominaux

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces verbes ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens ?

> Je m'en suis allé.
>   je suis allé.

Comment: Question liée: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/how-to-understand-je-men-vais.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pour répondre brièvement, *aller [+ complément de lieu]* est plus générique, et décrit un déplacement vers un lieu donné. Le verbe (intransitif) admet toujours un complément, on ne peut pas (hors effet littéraire assez rare) dire simplement *« Je vais. »* sans préciser où.

*S'en aller* (intransitif, lui aussi), en revanche, est (très souvent) utilisé sans complément, on ne précise pas forcément de destination. Cela signifie *quitter le lieu où l'on est actuellement*.

Pour les anglophones que la comparaison pourrait aider, *aller [quelque part]* correspondrait à *to go [somewhere]* alors que *s'en aller* se traduirait mieux par *to leave* ou *to go away*.

Answer (score 2):

Pour compléter la réponse de Romain, l'usage de ces locutions peut être différent :

> Je suis allé [toujours suivi d'un complément].

C'est un constat, un fait avéré : le *je* fait un compte rendu de ses déplacements, des lieux où il s'est rendu.

> Je m'en suis allé.

Insiste quant à lui sur le *moi* en sur-ajout du *je*, cette redondance n'est pas signe de tautologie, mais de la prise en compte du point de départ. Il est donc difficile de commencer une phrase par cette tournure qui implique d'avoir défini le *en* auparavant.

Soit avec le sens de

- départ d'une personne : *moi* (c'est de ma personne dont je parle, pas que de mon corps), de *en* (là ou j'étais), *je suis allé* (en dehors de ce *en*).
- de récit, de mouvement symbolique, de point de départ virtuel : *Après avoir fini…, je m'en suis allé conquérir le monde !*

Il peut toutefois être utilisé tel quel dans la tournure :

> Je m'en suis allé sans demander mon reste !

pour signifier que l'on a tout abandonné pour partir en vitesse devant une menace.
On peut aussi le remplacer par un plus familier :

> Je suis parti sans demander mon reste.