# Understanding "s’en retourna tout agitée"

Tags: syntaxe

I am trying to understand the highlighted phrase in this excerpt from Voltaire's Candide.

> Un jour, Cunégonde, en se promenant auprès du château, dans le petit bois qu’on appelait parc, vit entre des broussailles le docteur Pangloss qui donnait une leçon de physique expérimentale à la femme de chambre de sa mère, petite brune très jolie et très docile. Comme mademoiselle Cunégonde avait beaucoup de disposition pour les sciences, elle observa, sans souffler, les expériences réitérées dont elle fut témoin ; elle vit clairement la raison suffisante du docteur, les effets et les causes, et **s’en retourna tout agitée,** toute pensive, toute remplie du désir d’être savante, songeant qu’elle pourrait bien être la raison suffisante du jeune Candide, qui pouvait aussi être la sienne.

**Questions**

1. Am I correct to think that *se* connects with *retourna* to mean that Cunégonde came back and that *en* connects with *agitée* to mean that she was agitated with what she had seen (if one had to be precise about it, *les effets et les causes*)?
2. Assuming yes to 1, could one have said instead *se retourna tout en agitée* to make it more apparent where (to which verb) *se* and *en* belonged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - 1 : ***s'en*** retourner : revenir d'où l'on vient.
> - 2 : ***se*** retourner : retourner la tête et le corps pour voir ce qu'il y a derrière.

- *se retourner ... **en*** ... est incorrect
- *se retourner **en** étant agitée*, indiquerait seulement la façon dont Cunégonde se retourne

Comment: So I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: For any future readers, this seems related. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/how-to-understand-je-men-vais

Comment: Also from Northanger Abbey:  Votre amie, Mlle Thorpe, consentirait-elle à danser ? Mon frère serait très heureux de lui être présenté. / Sans hésitation, Catherine répondit que Mlle Thorpe désirait ne pas danser ; et, transmise la cruelle réponse, le capitaine **s’en alla.**