# on s'en va - exact meaning and structure?

Tags: grammaire

As I understand, the meaning of this phrase is: `we're leaving` or `we're going away`.  And yet, some questions remain.

Apparently, `on s'en va` is a generalization of: `on se va de object`, where `en` is a pronoun of an object.

**1) What is that object precisely?**

Is it the current place, the source of the movement or it's more a situation from where we're going away?

And there is another way to express a similar thing: `on'y va` which is a generalization of: `on va à object`.

Here, `à object` means a destination object, and `y` is a pronoun for that object (place).

Do natives reckon these two - just the same, i.e. `on s'en va` and `on'y va`?

(I personally think they're different as `on'y va` suggests that we're moving to some known location.)

**2) Why `se aller` is used here?**

And is it the only case when `aller` is used as a reflexive verb?

**3) What do you think on saying: `on va`?**

Is it a replacement of the two?

Comment: Oh, yeah, right. Thanks! I should have searched the other form of this: "je m'en vais". But let it be here for search engines.

Comment: The idiom in French is: s'en aller, to go away or to leave [implied: a place] If you want to say in French, "I'm leaving", you say: "Je m'en vais".  It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie. Have you btw visited the linked thread? I liked this reply: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2400/26260 it confirmed my expectations, as from the regular grammar point of view this phrase is build in a little odd way: `en` is useless here and doesn't refer to anything, and `se` makes `aller` reflexive, which is also a non-standard thing (a relic).

Comment: "The fact that the reflexive pronoun appears is specific to this locution and cannot be understood". Disagree. There is a huge difference between "s'en aller" and "aller". Fyi, in Spanish and Portuguese, the verbs to leave also are reflexive: irse and ir(se) embora. Je m'en vais. "I'm leaving [here]". Je vais à l'école. I go or am going to school.