# Meaning of "en" and "mouri" in Compère Guilleri (children song)

Tags: grammaire, paroles-de-chanson, en

This is from the children song "Compère Guilleri":

> Il était un p'tit homme
>  Appelé Guilleri,
>  Carabi,
>  Il
> s'**en** fut à la chasse,
>  A la chasse aux perdrix,
>  Carabi
> Titi carabi, Toto carabo,
>  Compère guilleri.
>  Te lairas-tu, te
> lairas-tu,
>  Te lairas-tu **mouri**.

How should I understand "en" and "mouri" grammatically?

I know that "en" may work in different ways (adverb, preposition, pronoun etc), but I'm not sure what's happening in this case.

About "mouri", I guess it's supposed to mean the infinitive "mourir", so where's the final "r"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***En*** is part of the verbal expression ***s'en aller***<sup>1</sup>, see for example [How to understand "Je m'en vais."?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2399)

***Lairas*** and ***mouri*** are used for ***laisseras*** and ***mourir***.

The latter to rhyme with ***carabi*** and the former possibly just for the fun of dropping another consonant.

There are other cases of poetic licence later on:

> *Pour voir ses chiens couri*
> ...
> *Et Guilleri tombi*
> ...
> *Guill'ri les embrassit*

[image]

*Journal des écoliers et des écolières*, 1903 ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comp%C3%A8re_Guilleri))

A 1860 version of that song uses the same wording outside a slight variation with ***titi/toto*** and the last name spelled **Guillery**.

[image]

Victor Séjour, *Compère Guillery, Drame en cinq actes et neuf tableaux*.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Despite the fact that ***fut*** is technically a conjugation of the verb *être*. See @Livresque's [reply](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50786/1109) and Didier's [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50785/meaning-of-en-and-mouri-in-comp%C3%A8re-guilleri-children-song/50787#comment105585_50786).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a phonetic copy of the lyrics, or just a poetic/lyrical version. A popular search engine returned Musixmatch listing *mourir* as you suspected. It does not mean anything different.

> Te lairas-tu, te lairas-tu 
> Te lairas-tu mourir?

Lai'ras a contraction of laisseras, musical interpretation not unlike how leaving the -r off mourir helps with the rhyme scheme.

Then you have the verb [s'en aller](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/french-english/s-en-aller).  It's the third [entry](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Aller) for *aller* and it means to go away.  In this context, he went off to (the) hunt, went away to hunt.  Similar to "a-hunting we will go" in an English children's song of a similar time period.  S'en aller is fixed.  Also note the usage in the passé simple.

> Rem. 1. Aux temps composés, en précède normalement l'auxil. : je m'en
> suis allé; je me suis en allé est familier. **2. Pour l'emploi littér.
> il s'en fut**, au lieu de il s'en alla, cf. être

Comment: Note that “fut” is from “être” and not “aller”, hence the “cf. être” in the last quote, and the corresponding remark in the definition of “[_fut_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fut)” on the same site.